# Why does extracting a boolean from a union type say that boolean is not equal to true?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

This is a general understanding problem that I am having. While it is derived from material-ui, I believe it is a general typescript issue. I was not able to re-create the problem with my own types so I will just use material-ui to explain the issue. Working with the codesandbox will make it way easier to explore the types: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-snowflake-v9h98n?file=/demo.tsx)

Here is the code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import InputUnstyled, { InputUnstyledProps } from "@mui/base/InputUnstyled";

const CustomInput = ({
  multiline,
  ...props
}: InputUnstyledProps): JSX.Element => {
            // V Error here
  return <InputUnstyled multiline={multiline} {...props} />;
};

export default function UnstyledInputBasic() {
  return <CustomInput multiline={false} />;
}
```

Ignore contrived extraction of multiline. The error states that `Types of property 'multiline' are incompatible. Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'true'`.

This makes sense when you dive a bit deeper. `InputUnstyledProps` is (more-or-less) defined as:
`(SingleLineInputUnstyledProps | MultiLineInputUnstyledProps) & UseInputParameters & { ...input stuff }`

The key here being `SingleLineInput` vs `MultiLineInput` which are mutually exclusive. `SingleLineInput` hardcodes `multiline` to `false`. `MultiLineInput` sees `multiline` hardcoded as `true`. This also makes sense from a HTML standpoint. Can't have a single line input with multiline.

As a result, I can't pass booleans into `multiline`. I tried hardcoding the other values that go along with a `true` or `false` `multiline` value but it still didn't work:

```
    <InputUnstyled
      multiline={multiline}
      maxRows={multiline ? 12 : undefined}
      minRows={multiline ? 4 : undefined}
      rows={multiline ? 2 : undefined}
      type={multiline ? undefined : "text"}
      {...props}
    />
```

Where is the gap in my understanding?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, but it sounds like MUI expects `true | undefined`, which enforces the `<Tag multiline />` syntax, rather than allowing a bool to be passed in.

Comment: @DBS Not quite. As confusing as it may be to write it this way, MUI is expecting `true | false` but not `boolean`. You'll need to check the sandbox and inspect the types to see what I really mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript will simply look at the types of the expression you pass in.

`multiline` is `boolean`
`maxRows` is `number | undefined`

etc..

So in the eyes of the typesystem, you could potentially get false and number here.

To make it understand that the different props actually depend on each other, you need to use type [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) properly.

Something like

```
const CustomInput = ({
  multiline,
  type,
  maxRows,
  minRows,
  rows,
  ...props
}: InputUnstyledProps): JSX.Element => {
  return multiline ? (
    <InputUnstyled
      multiline
      maxRows={maxRows ?? 12}
      minRows={minRows ?? 4}
      rows={rows ?? 2}
      {...props}
    />
  ) : (
    <InputUnstyled type={type} {...props} />
  );
};
```

will do the trick. Here it can clearly see that if multiline is true, then and only then will the different row props be used.

Type will only be used if multiline is false and so on.

Comment: I was well aware of type narrowing but never thought to use it here. I suppose the clue here was that we have two strictly defined types where props depend on each other so we need to narrow down which one we are configuring. Thanks!